# How to Implement Pagination for Shop Module with Divi Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

I currently have a web store setup with Divi and am using the Divi Shop Module inside a template from the Divi Library. From the Divi Library this template is connected to a file within my child theme named archive-products-hand-guns.php. By assigning the Divi Library Template number to the archive-product file it allows me to customize each category according to the Divi Library Template Specified.

The problem I can not solve is that I am using the Shop Module specified with a product category within each page to show the products on a category level. However Divi Shop Module does not have a setting to implement pagination. I am trying to copy and paste the original archive-product.php pagination code to the new archive-product-hand-guns.php in order for the category page to show pagination but I am having no success.

I tried looking everywhere for an answer but can not seem to find one.

Can someone help me properly insert the woo_pagination() function within my php file so that it shows pagination for all the products within that category.

Link to category page: http://publifiedlabs.com/exatactical/product-category/hand-guns/

Here is the code to archive-products-hand-guns.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' );

     echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="1128"][/et_pb_section]');
     echo woo_pagination(); //This is how I am guessing it should be inserted?


get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

This is the original php section for pagination in my archive-products.php within my woocoomerce folder inside plugins folder

```
<?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
            ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
            ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: you are missing a semicolon at echo woo_pagination();

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the code with the semicolon. However this did not solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up finding a solution to this. It was right in front of me all along, lol. First I needed to install "Shortcode Pagination for Woocommerce". Without this plugin this solution will not work. Below is my Updated PHP file for the Category Page.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' );

     echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="1128"][/et_pb_section]');
     echo woocommerce_pagination();

get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

All I needed to do was add: echo woocommerce_pagination();

Took me days to figure this out. I have this posted just incase anyone else is having the same problem.